# how can i calculate the number of arcs of a whighed graph using adjacency list & adjacency matrix "

Tags: graph

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH1JB.png)

i represented this graph using adjacency matrix the code down below

```
 NBR_OF_ARCS (Graphe:Table[1..n,1..n] )
    nbrOFArcs←0 
    for i ← 1, 2,..., n do 
        for j ← 1, 2,..., n do 
           if Graphe[i, j] >= 0 then
                nbrOFArcs←nbrOFArcs+1
```

> ```
> is the algorithm calculating the number of arcs of the graph that i wrote correct "
> ```

& how can i calculate the nbr of arcs using adjacency list ;

Comment: The code you shared is calculating the number of edges in the graph.

Comment: There are number of ways you may improve your question. (i) make sure your attached image is visible to the post, (ii) update formatting and typos to improve clarity.